# Issue showing Google+ sign-in button in FF and IE. Works in Chrome

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am trying to add the google+ sign in button to my page. I have followed the steps in the developer docs: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

If the user is logged in to google, then it works fine in all browsers.
If the user is not logged in to google, it only shows the sign in button in Chrome, but not in FF and IE. Both in FF and IE the html button that is rendered has a height and width of 1px. If I change the height and width directly in the browser, the button is there and functional.

Does anyone know what it would have this behavior only in FF and IE, but not in Chrome?

This is my html code:

```
    <span id="signinButton">
        <span
          class="g-signin"
          data-callback="googleCallback"
          data-clientid="###key###"
          data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
          data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
          data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
        </span>
     </span>

     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
```

And my JS code:

```
function googleCallback(authResult)     {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        console.log("ok");
    } else {
        // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
        // Possible error values:
        //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
        //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
        //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
      }
}
```

Comment: You code isn't valid. You are missing the beginning of the `f` statement inside `googleCallback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have received no replies, I will post here how I bypassed this problem.

**It is a very dirty way. I don't like it. if anyone finds a better way please let me know**

I updated the googleCallback function so it changes the CSS of the button. It modifies the height and width:

```
function googleCallback(authResult)     {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        console.log("ok");
    } else {
        // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
        // Possible error values:
        //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
        //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
        //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
      }
}
```